# Augmented Reality in Hybrid mobile application

Tags: cordova, augmented-reality, wikitude, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a hybrid mobile application using jQueryMobile and phonegap. Now I need to implement the augmented reality in camera view to the application. I got wikitude for this purpose. Can I do the functionality mentioned in the following link using hybrid mobile application?

http://www.wikitude.com/showcases/active-website-augments-real-estate/

I got some sample application here 
https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap/tree/master/Android

But I am confused whether I can use this for hybrid mobile application (only html, js and css files), since these samples include WikitudePlugin.java files.

Please help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Wikitude Forum](http://forum.wikitude.com/home/-/message_boards/view_message/259451).

Your question was answered there already (quote from user "Caroline")

"The Wikitude Plugin is a Phonegap Plugin. Phonegap Plugins add native (for Android: Java, for iOS: Obj-C) code files to your project. This native code supports functions you can call from within your hybrid code. Therefore, your hybrid code remains hybrid, but before deploying to different platforms, you should provide the Phonegap Plugin (such as Wikitude Plugin) for that platform as well. "