# Hybrid app development with geo location, augmented reality like pokemon go. Is it possible?

Tags: cordova, geolocation, augmented-reality, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an application project, which is similar to Pokemon GO. That means I need to build an app, which has AR and Geo Location features. I would like to build a hybrid app for this project, so I can deploy it for iOS and Android, unless I couldn't find any useful information about that.

I found only this post on stackoverflow

[Augmented Reality in Hybrid mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107895/augmented-reality-in-hybrid-mobile-application)

In this post wikitude is recommended but wikitude is not free, that's why I can't use it. Is there any alternative?

Cheers!!!

Comment: both cordova and phonegap are both free to use

Comment: I meant actually wikitude, I edited my question, but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used wikitude in several hybrid projects and for sure you are able to combine it with geolocation services.
As I searched the web for alternative for hybrids apps and augmented reality I found nothing reasonable.

You can always use wikitude without license but you will have watermarks placed on camera view.

You might check http://catchoom.com/ - that product also had some cordova plugin but it didn't meet our expectations that time. Maybe it has developed

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will help me to continue on my research.